# CSS text disappear

Tags: css

I coded this css, why the 'Search' disappear ? thanks

```
<h2 class="domain_header">Search</h2>


.domain_header {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border-left: 0px solid #06f;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0066FF;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: Because you set the text color to `#fff` (white), and the background is white as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your text to a different colour.

```
.domain_header {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border-left: 0px solid #06f;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0066FF;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0 0 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you have white text on a white background

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing Ctrl+A, if 'Search' is then visible then you know it is because you have white text on a white background as  @John said, if not then we will need to see more of your code.